# Wordpress pagination doesn't work on PLAIN Permailnk

Tags: wordpress

I have created custom post in my Wp Page, and I set Pagination for this Page. But when I changed Permalink in PLAIN, pagination doesn't work. Url of page displayed in this form: "domain/wordpress/?page_id=2575&lang=de#038;lang=depage/2"

Code of Pagination is:

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

if (empty($pagerange)) {
$pagerange = 2;
}

global $paged;
if (empty($paged)) {
$paged = 1;
}
  if ($numpages == '') {
   global $wp_query;
   $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
      $numpages = 1;
     }
   }

$pagination_args = array(
'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
'format'          => 'page/%#%',
'total'           => $numpages,
'current'         => $paged,
'show_all'        => False,
'end_size'        => 1,
'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
'prev_next'       => True,
'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
'type'            => 'plain',
'add_args'        => false,
'add_fragment'    => ''
);

$paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

 if ($paginate_links) {
   echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
   echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $paged . " of " .   $numpages . "</span> ";
   echo $paginate_links;
  echo "</nav>";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default WP query var for page number is "paged". In url = wordpress/?paged=2575

EDIT: if paginate_links() doesn't generate desired format, it's because your input args. 'base' determines url structure and "%_%" is placeholder for 'format', which is in your case set to non-plain. Try array( 'format' => '?paged=%#%' ).

UPDATE: change this code:

```
global $paged;
if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
}
```

for

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
```

You have to include "paged" variable in url to make sure, it will load it and paste it into links created inside your pagination. Post me url in href="" attribute from your actual pagination.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work and with 'format' => '?paged=%#%'

Comment: Could you provide access to your site? See UPDATE.

Comment: For further analyze (since you need to debug your code) please provide real url or post the generated link.

Comment: I have hosted in local host. URL is: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2573&lang=en#038;lang=en&page/2

Comment: And if you enter http://localhost/wordpress/?paged=2573&lang=en#038;lang=en does it make any changes? I changed "my_page" for "paged". The "&page/2" at the end of the url is redundant.